# MAT Files attached to an email are blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, email, smtp

I create an email with attachments using the following function.

```
def createEmaiLWithAttachments_Filepaths(self,send_to_emails, subject_text , main_message_text , attachment_filepaths, msgID=None, inReplyTo=None, html=False): 
    try: 
        fromEmail = self.from_email_total
        
        if (type(main_message_text) == list) or (type(main_message_text) == tuple): 
            total_text = ""
            for line in main_message_text:
                if type(line) == str: 
                    total_text = total_text + line + "\n"
            main_message_text = total_text

        mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart()
        if type(send_to_emails) == list: 
            mimeMessage['to'] = ", ".join(send_to_emails)
        else: 
            mimeMessage['to'] = send_to_emails
        
        mimeMessage['from'] = fromEmail
        mimeMessage['subject'] = subject_text
        if inReplyTo != None: 
            mimeMessage["In-Reply-To"] = inReplyTo
            mimeMessage["References"] = inReplyTo
        if msgID != None: 
            mimeMessage['Message-ID'] = msgID
        if html: 
            msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, 'html')
        else: 
            msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, "plain")
        mimeMessage.attach(msg)
        
        attachments = list()
        for attachment_filepath in attachment_filepaths:
            attachment_filepath = fr"{attachment_filepath}"
            with open(attachment_filepath, 'rb') as FID:
                file_instance_bytes = FID.read()
                
            file_name = Path(attachment_filepath).name
            to_attach = (file_name,file_instance_bytes)
            attachments.append(to_attach)
                

        totalSizeOf = 0
        MAX_BYTES = 50000000
        for attachment in attachments: 
            attachment_name = attachment[0]
            attachment_instance = attachment[1]
            attachmentSizeBytes = sys.getsizeof(attachment_instance)
            if totalSizeOf + attachmentSizeBytes > MAX_BYTES:
                self.HifiGmailAPILogger.error(f"The attachment ({attachment_name}) not attached due to the attachment causing the email to exceed maximum limit ({MAX_BYTES}) bytes")
                continue
            else:
                totalSizeOf = totalSizeOf + attachmentSizeBytes
            content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment_name)
            if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
                content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
            main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)    
            if main_type == 'text': 
                try: 
                    msg = MIMEText(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
                except: 
                    attachment_instance = attachment_instance.decode("utf-8")
                    msg = MIMEText(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'image':
                msg = MIMEImage(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'audio':
                msg = MIMEAudio(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            else:
                msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
                msg.set_payload(attachment_instance) 
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment_name)
            mimeMessage.attach(msg) 

        raw_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_string().encode()).decode()
        theMessage = {'raw': raw_string}
        return theMessage
    except: 
        self.GmailAPILogger.error("An error occurred in createEmaiLWithAttachments")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GmailAPILogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

It generally works. However, the problem I have been encountering is attaching `.mat` files. To clarify, I can attach the `.mat` files using this function and they arrive. However, the `.mat` file is invalid. Sometimes, the file cannot be read due to errors in the header. Other times, I can load the file, but it doesn't load any variables into the workspace. Rather, the workspace remains empty, even though I can see the `.mat` file is like 217KB.

I also tried to add:

```
if '.mat' in file_name:
    file_instance_bytes = scipy.io.loadmat(attachment_filepath)
else:
    with open(attachment_filepath, 'rb') as FID:
        file_instance_bytes = FID.read()
```

However, that causes several errors in the part:

```
raw_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_string().encode()).decode()
```

What can I do?

The CRC SHA256 is different between the original, attached file and the downloaded file.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following

```
from email import encoders


encoders.encode_base64(msg)
```

where `msg` is the attachment. I run that function on each attachment.

```
def createEmaiLWithAttachments_Filepaths(self,send_to_emails, subject_text , main_message_text , attachment_filepaths, msgID=None, inReplyTo=None, html=False): 
    try: 
        fromEmail = self.from_email_total
        
        if (type(main_message_text) == list) or (type(main_message_text) == tuple): 
            total_text = ""
            for line in main_message_text:
                if type(line) == str: 
                    total_text = total_text + line + "\n"
            main_message_text = total_text

        mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart()
        if type(send_to_emails) == list: 
            mimeMessage['to'] = ", ".join(send_to_emails)
        else: 
            mimeMessage['to'] = send_to_emails
        
        mimeMessage['from'] = fromEmail
        mimeMessage['subject'] = subject_text
        if inReplyTo != None: 
            mimeMessage["In-Reply-To"] = inReplyTo
            mimeMessage["References"] = inReplyTo
        if msgID != None: 
            mimeMessage['Message-ID'] = msgID
        if html: 
            msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, 'html')
        else: 
            msg= MIMEText(main_message_text, "plain")
        mimeMessage.attach(msg)
        
        attachments = list()
        for attachment_filepath in attachment_filepaths:
            attachment_filepath = fr"{attachment_filepath}"
            with open(attachment_filepath, 'rb') as FID:
                file_instance_bytes = FID.read()
                
            file_name = Path(attachment_filepath).name
            to_attach = (file_name,file_instance_bytes)
            attachments.append(to_attach)
                

        totalSizeOf = 0
        MAX_BYTES = 50000000
        for attachment in attachments: 
            attachment_name = attachment[0]
            attachment_instance = attachment[1]
            attachmentSizeBytes = sys.getsizeof(attachment_instance)
            if totalSizeOf + attachmentSizeBytes > MAX_BYTES:
                self.HifiGmailAPILogger.error(f"The attachment ({attachment_name}) not attached due to the attachment causing the email to exceed maximum limit ({MAX_BYTES}) bytes")
                continue
            else:
                totalSizeOf = totalSizeOf + attachmentSizeBytes
            content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment_name)
            if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
                content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
            main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)    
            if main_type == 'text': 
                try: 
                    msg = MIMEText(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
                except: 
                    attachment_instance = attachment_instance.decode("utf-8")
                    msg = MIMEText(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'image':
                msg = MIMEImage(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'audio':
                msg = MIMEAudio(attachment_instance, _subtype=sub_type)
            else:
                msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
                msg.set_payload(attachment_instance) 
                encoders.encode_base64(msg)
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment_name)
            mimeMessage.attach(msg) 

        raw_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_string().encode()).decode()
        theMessage = {'raw': raw_string}
        return theMessage
    except: 
        self.GmailAPILogger.error("An error occurred in createEmaiLWithAttachments")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GmailAPILogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Sends all attachments just fine now, including `.mat` files.